# How to optimize the following code in java where I've to get bitwise OR of two very long binary strings?

Tags: java, string, bitwise-or

I've written the following code to get the **bitwise or** of two strings. But, it's taking way too long when I pass long strings. How can I *optimize* it?

```
 static String or_str(String s1, String s2){
            String result="";
            for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
                if(s1.charAt(i)=='1'||s2.charAt(i)=='1')
                result+="1";
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to assemble the result, and set its capacity (with the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(int)) or a call to [`ensureCapacity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#ensureCapacity(int))) equal to the length of `s1`.

Comment: Perhaps you should use an `else` in there as well, your current code will produce a String containing `1`s only.

Comment: I've to count only 1s @Amongalen

Comment: so then just make result (and method type) to an int, and it will be far faster

Comment: Then why create that String at the first place? Just create a simple int counter and increment it inside of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just the amount of ones, like can be found on comments, you can use sample like this:

```
static int countBitwiseOr(String s1, String s2) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) == '1' || s2.charAt(i) == '1')
            result += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

to avoid lot of calculation overhead.

**Edit suggested API conform solution proposed in comments**

If you need to rest API conform (return a string containing all the positive results) you then still can:

> with Java 11

```
 static String or_str(String s1, String s2){
    return "1".repeat(countBitwiseOr(s1,s2));
 }
```

> with Java 11

```
 static String or_str(String s1, String s2){
   return Stream.generate(() -> "1").limit(countBitwiseOr(s1,s2)).collect(joining());
 }
```

Comment: Or, `return "1".repeat(result);` if you *really* need to preserve API.

Comment: Thanks, added it to the solution. (also in older Java Style)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real bitwise "OR" you need also to output a zero in case your condition does not match. If you want to improve performance you know the length of the output so instead of creating a new string on each iteration you can use a character array with a pre-defined length from the start.

Here is a simple implementation of a bitwise or for strings which returns a string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "1011010100100101110";
    String s2 = "011011101101001000100110001";
    System.out.println(or_str(s1, s2));
}

static String or_str(String s1, String s2){
    char[] res = new char[s1.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
        if(s1.charAt(i)=='1'||s2.charAt(i)=='1')
            res[i] ='1';
        else
            res[i] ='0';
    }
    return new String(res);
}
```

If you run this, the output will be:

```
1111111111110111111
```